# How to combine the top unite (signature) and the table itself into one block so that they don't appear on different pages after compilation?

Tags: tables, captions

[image]

Please, Write a needed code to unite caption and table.

Comment: How tot you create the table and its caption?

Comment: the caption to the table should always be above it and on the same page

Comment: Your requirements are clear. What is still unclear is how you produced the screenshot you showed. Please prepare a minimal working example and include it in your question. A caption that appears on a different page than the table it belongs to definitely is not the default behavior.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).